# Find occurrences of sequences in sound wave

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have quite basic knowledge of mathematics.

Consider two axis, time and dB (sound levels).

My question is if it's possible, using fourier or any other method, to find how many occurrences of specific dB values in a row exist.

For instance I want to find how many times the dB sequence 20,40,60 exists.

Sorry if I don't make sense !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just search through the file.  Go through until you find a $20$, then see if it is followed by $40,60$ and count $1.$  If it isn't, go back to looking for $20$'s.

Comment: I can not do that because it's time consuming. I tried it, but I cannot use it because of how long it takes.

Comment: I don't know how to use an FFT to do this.  An FFT is of order $n \log n$, while this is of order $n$, so this will be faster.

Comment: I see... thanks !

Comment: You should probably look at how you are reading the file and what language you are using.  If it is three minutes of music sampled at 44 kHz, you have about 8 million entries.  You can search that in seconds in Python and a fully complied language will be faster yet.